# Litecoin vs Bitcoin Digest Signing

Tags: cryptocurrency, scrypt, litecoin

I'm trying to learn more about Litecoin and have understood how Bitcoin transactions work.  What I'm not sure about is where Scrypt comes into the picture.  I know it's used as the proof of work, but internally as far as transactions are concerned, how is Scrypt used?  I can find virtually no documentation on Litecoin save from having to debug a decently large codebase.

- A Litecoin wallet address is a SHA256/RipeMD160 of a public key and a few other things.  So no Scrypt there.
- Now for Bitcoin, in order to sign a raw transaction (assuming you've done all your ScriptPubKey and stuff), you take the hex and you SHA256(SHA256(raw_transaction_bytes)), you then use your scp256k1 elliptic curve and sign the result of the above.  This produces the SigScript that you insert into your completed transaction.

Okay... where is Scrypt involved here?  Or it is not involved in the creation and signing of a Litecoin transaction?

Comment: Bitcoin and derivatives have their own SE site; something to consider if you don't get an answer here

Comment: Have you got a URL for this site?  Litecoin info is scarce to say the least and there is an excellent answer here for signing a bitcoin transaction.

Comment: I think it was bitcoin.stackexchange.com but googling "bitcoin stackexchangel should bring it up :)

Comment: Internally signing uses double sha256 in both bitcoin and litecoin. Scrypt is used just for proof of work in Litecoin. Even block id is calculated with double sha256.